How to get nice math typesetting in a Github README generated in R with `rmarkdown::render`?
If you look at the README of this Githib repo you will see that the maths rendering is not very nice. These are images:

I generated this README from a Rmd file using this YAML header:
---
title: "The 'jack' package: Jack and other symmetric polynomials"
output: github_document
editor_options: 
  chunk_output_type: console
---

On the other hand, on this repo the maths rendering is quite nice. I wrote it simply by directly typing the md file, there's no post-processing.
So, with rmarkdown::render in R, how should we proceed to get a nice maths rendering?

The github_document format has a math_method argument.  Maybe try some non-default settings there?  BTW, the first link you give in the question is to a different version of the README that doesn't seem to include that paragraph, so I can't try this out and recommend what method to use.

@user2554330 Thanks, will try this argument. You're right, sorry, I just forgot to recompile the Rmd to md.

Credit to @user2554330 for the solution, and thanks to the doc.
Now I'm using this YAML header and the maths are perfect:
---
title: "The 'jack' package: Jack and other symmetric polynomials"
output: 
  github_document:
    math_method: NULL
editor_options: 
  chunk_output_type: console
---

(of course this is unrelated to editor_options).
